# Python: Extracting mean and chronological information from grouped data

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, timestamp, mean

I have the following data:

```
 cluster    col1        col2        timestamp
0   1      34.000000    89.320000   2021-07-13 21:15:11.232
1   1      97.540001    29.000000   2021-06-13 14:22:11.682
2   3      NaN          1.030000    2021-04-01 10:10:45.623
3   1      NaN          22.670000   2021-06-13 10:54:00.329
4   1      92.339996    NaN         2021-05-13 13:12:01.000
5   2      43.200001    22.450001   2021-03-02 17:05:02.342
6   2      NaN          45.000000   2021-06-13 14:17:11.454
7   2      92.230003    10.000000   2021-06-13 11:22:11.311
8   3      13.000000    1.320000    2021-06-13 18:22:11.324
```

To group by cluster and set chronologically I do:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby("cluster").apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by = "timestamp"))
```

My goal is to compute the means of col1 and col2 for each cluster and extract the earliest and latest time. In other words, I'd like the following output:

```
    cluster    col1_mean    col2_mean   start_time              end_time
0   1          74.626666    46.996667   2021-05-13 13:12:01.000 2021-07-13 21:15:11.232
1   2          67.715002    25.816667   2021-03-02 17:05:02.342 2021-06-13 14:17:11.454
2   3          13.0         1.175       2021-04-01 10:10:45.623 2021-06-13 18:22:11.324
```

However, the timestamp is giving me some trouble as I can't see how to compute the mean of the columns and extract the time.

I can compute the mean by cluster when the timestamp is excluded by doing:

```
df_excluding_time.groupby("cluster").mean()

>>
    col1    col2
cluster     
1   74.626663   46.996666
2   67.715004   25.816668
3   13.000000   1.175000
```

What's the best approach to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `agg` function on the groupby object.

```
df_grouped = df.sort_values(['cluster','timestamp']).groupby("cluster").agg({'col1':'mean', 'col2':'mean', 'timestamp':['first', 'last']})
```

Then your column index would be a multiindex `[('col1','mean'),('col2','mean'),('timestamp','first'), ('timestamp','last')]`. To put it in the format you want, you could just manually do

```
df_grouped.columns = ['col1_mean','col2_mean','start_time','end_time']
```

Finally, if you want the cluster column to be a column rather than an index, simply do

```
df_grouped = df_grouped.reset_index()
```

Comment: For a large dataset (around 30,000 observations), would this still being an acceptable approach or would you reckon a loop would be more efficient?

Comment: I don't know, but given how well engineered pandas is, I would suspect this would still work (and perhaps even be optimal) for large datasets.